# How to change data in a column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

Here are my columns in my table SystemSpecCategories

```
 ID (int) 
 Group ID  (int)
 Description   (varchar)
```

My GroupID has values from 1-9. I would like to run a query that changes all GroupID values that are 8, and change them to 9. I am very new to SQL and I have tried :

```
 UPDATE SystemSpecCategories
 SET GroupID = 9
 WHERE GroupID = 8
```

This through the error "8" is not a valid column name
I think I may be way off with that query but Ive tried another with REPLACE

```
 SELECT REPLACE(Group_ID, "8", "9")
 FROM SystemSpecCategories
```

I thought I was straight on with that one but it through an error saying incorrect syntax. Could anyone help me out? Id greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Your first attempt was correct.  UPDATE lets you change the values in the table.  SELECT is read only.  I do note your list of columns says "Group ID" with a space.  Can you provide the actual CREATE TABLE command?

Comment: REPLACE computes a string replacement; it doesn't do anything to the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first try is correct.

The problem might be that your column is called `Group ID` (with a space).

If that is case, try:

```
UPDATE SystemSpecCategories
SET [Group ID] = 9
WHERE [Group ID] = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you always add "_" when you have a column name which is same as a sql statement.

UPDATE SystemSpecCategories
SET GROUP_ID = 9
WHERE GROUP_ID IS 8;